# Leaflet JS Markers do not fire 'tap/click' events in Android WebView.

Tags: javascript, click, markers, leaflet

Leaflet JS Markers do not fire 'tap/click' events in Android WebView.  I've tested it in Android 2.x -> 4.0?  I'm using mapbox + wax + leaflet JS.  Has anyone had this working?  Thanks!!

```
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(_lat, _long), { icon: _icon, clickable: true,
draggable: false });

marker.on('click', function () {
    //never fires in android WebView or stock browser
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes click event is not work on mobile browser you can use another event like touchstart as given below

```js
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(_lat, _long), { icon: _icon, clickable: true,
    draggable: false });
    
marker.on('touchstart', function(e) {
    // Do your stuff here
});
```